# Vue.js - can not add date/timepicker to the html element rendered by vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue.js component where there are groups of text fields ( group of a text field labelled "Start" and another text field labelled "To") bound to a Vue array ( s.timespans) .

What I want is, when I add another group of text field by adding element to the ( s.timespans ) array, all the textfields get date/timepicker. But unfortunately, now only the first group of field gets the date/timepicker and the other groups don't. What is the right way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<template id="settings">
<div v-for="(k,slot) in s.timespans" class="row mb5">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label><?php _e( 'From', 'smps' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" v-model="slot.from">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <label><?php _e( 'To', 'smps' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" v-model="slot.to">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-xs br0" @click="remove_timeslot(k)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

<template>
```

The Vue js code

```
Vue.component( 'settings', {
        template : '#settings',
        data : function () {
            return {
                s : {
                    timespans : [
                        {from : '', to : ''}
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        methods : {
            add_timeslot : function () {
                Vue.set(this.s.timespans,this.s.timespans.length,{from:'',to:''});
                $('.datepicker').datetimepicker();
            },
            remove_timeslot : function (k) {
                this.s.timespans.splice(k,1);
            },

        },

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this then the DOM will be finished rendering, not before [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick):

```
        add_timeslot : function () {
            Vue.set(this.s.timespans,this.s.timespans.length,{from:'',to:''});
            this.$nextTick(function () {
              $('.datepicker').datetimepicker();
            });
        },
```

when the function in nextTick is executed, the DOM Element will be rendered.